# how to use bc inside a for-loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, bc

Inside a loop I have a variable to be used for the calculation, using `bc`, of another variable.
However, the result I get is totally incorrect. I have 32 files, named `test0`, `test1` and so on.
My script reads as follow:

```
for i in {0..31}; do
  declare x$i=$(wc -l < test$i)
  declare y$i=$(echo $x$i/10 | bc) 
done
```

for the variable `x`, I get the good results, i.e. each `x$i`stores the number of lines of the correspondent `test$i`. Then I'd like to simple know how much is 10% of each `x$i` and stores it in variables `y$i`.  And, as I said above, I get completely wrong results using that script.
For example, for `x0`=155287510 I got `y0`=20.

Comment: What results do you get? What results are you expecting? What is `test$i`?

Comment: @terdon I've just edited my question

Comment: Maybe you need to set the `scale`.... `echo "scale=2;10/3" | bc`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `$x$i` is not the value of a variable named `x$i` but the catenation of the values of the variables `x` and `i`.

You could convert your script to use Bash arrays easily, but it seems like you would be better off doing this in Awk.

```
declare -a x
declare -a y
for i in {0..31}; do
  x[$i]=$(wc -l < test$i)
  y[$i]=$(echo "${x[$i]}"/10 | bc) 
done
```

If you just want the result from the calculation,

```
wc -l test[0-9] test[12][0-9] test3[01] |
awk '{$1 /= 10 }1'
```

Comment: I don't think its even worth spawning `bc` every loop iteration, when the shell will happily divide by 10 itself `y[$i]=$(( ${x[$i]} / 10 ))`.  (Of course `bc` is more useful if decimal results are required.)

Comment: Or if you don't care about rounding, simply drop the last digit -- `${x[$i]%?}`

Comment: I considered that but it would result on an empty string for 1-digit numbers